# Custom hook fires every render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, react-custom-hooks

I want to run a callback when a component mounts, but not on each render. Using `useEffect` and an empty dependency array created warnings. I read on a different thread which I now can't find that this can be achieved by creating a custom hook:

```
import {useRef} from "react";

const useInitialise = (callback) => {
    //TODO this is running every render!
    const runOnce = useRef(false);
    if (!runOnce.current) {
        callback();
        runOnce.current = true;
    }
}

export default useInitialise;
```

Usage:

```
useInitialise(() => {
    //callback
});
```

This is instead of using:

```
useEffect(() => {
        //callback
    }, []);
```

As this generates warnings. I understand that the hook will be called on each render, but why is the `runOnce.current` not preventing the callback being run twice?

Answer (score 0):

[Found the thread!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook?rq=1)

I should use a state to track mounted/unmounted, then useEffect to call the callback only if either mounted or callback change:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

const useInitialise = (callback) => {
    const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false)
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!mounted) {
            setMounted(true);
            callback();
        }
    }, [mounted, callback]);
}

export default useInitialise;
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using a `useEffect` with empty deps array. In fact I would prefer that over this stateful approach

Comment: Then why is there a warning about it?

Comment: what warnings are you seeing?

Comment: If the callback is “getEntries” for example - it’s not included in the array as 1. Doesn’t change and 2. That causes an infinite loop. I understand the warning is because there’s a variable in the useEffect but not array, so the aim is to have a way of executing code on first mount only without warnings

React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getEntries'.
Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Comment: Did you wrap the callback in a `useCallback` to memoize it? Then it would be safe to include in the dependencies array